# Checking values and inserting in to column of existing row

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment I am working on a form that on submit goes to a payment gateway to allow the user to pay for the event they registered for. The payments and form are working correctly.

I store the generated merchant session ID and other values in to my database (mySQL) when the user goes to make a payment.

The problem I am having is how do I check that once payment is made and the payment site returns the values that the merchant session ID is the same and update the payment status column in that existing row.

I'm really not sure how I do this with php and I think that is where the problem lies. I have been googling but to no avail..

What I've tried has been along the lines of:

```
$merchant = $_GET['ms'];
$status = $_GET['ec'];
if ($merchant == 'session')
{
$sql ="UPDATE $tbl_name SET paystatus='$status' WHERE session = '$merchant'";
}
```

I'm not sure if I need to specify to update the column of that exact row where merchant == session or how.

Comment: It probably depends on the payment gateway you are using and they data they send back to you. Which gateway are you using?

Comment: I'm using paystation.co.nz

They send back the merchant session (ms) error code (ec) if error code = 0 the transaction is successful. 

What I want to do is check if the returned merchant session value is equal to one of the stored merchant sessions and then update the paystatus column in that row. I'm just really not sure how I go about this

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Answer (score 0):

```
$merchant = $_GET['ms'];//merchant
$status = $_GET['ec'];//error code
$query = "SELECT `merchant` FROM `tbl` WHERE `merchant` = '".$merchant."'";//select merchant column where merchant variable is in your table
$result = mysqli_query($query); //query
if ($result&&$status!=0)//if query succeeds and error != 0
{
$sql ="UPDATE $tbl_name SET paystatus='".$status."' WHERE session = '".$merchant."'";//update
$doquery = mysqli_query($sql);//query
}
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: Seems like a better attempt than mine but still doesn't seem to be storing the error code in status. Also had error  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters. Changed that to mysql_query().

Comment: @Nathan oops, sorry, forgot that second parameter. Storing the error code in status is not involved in my code. It is your job to make sure that is is received through $_GET

Comment: But in the line UPDATE $tbl_name SET paystatus='".$status."' WHERE session = '".$merchant."'" is this not storing $status(which is $_GET['ec'] into paystatus?

Sorry just realised I probably should have said paystatus not status in my first comment